# Application quit unexpectely when I run it with Instruments iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, crash, instruments

My application is crashing when I'm launching it in Instruments. No message is shown when I'm pressing Ignore. What could be the reason behind this? The application is running fine in simulator.

Comment: I get the same issue, with message "Target failed to run : Remote exception encountered : 'Failed to get task for pid 921'". On different mac I got same results with message 'Automation not supported on this device'. In both cases it was iPhone 3G, OS 4.0, sdk 4

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this cleared up many times by restarting Xcode, Instruments, the device, the Mac or combinations of them or all of them.